# Что означает оператор '|='?

Tags: python

Столкнулся с этим в видеоуроке на ютубе, вместо метода .update или .add для добавления элементов в множество автор использовал оператор |= . Поискал в интернете | - это побитовое ИЛИ. Прошу объяснить чайнику простыми словами почему это работает.

Comment: То же самое, что и `a = a | b` - для множеств это операция их объединения

Comment: Благодарю, так понятней

Comment: Одни и те же операторы для разных типов данных могут иметь разное действие. Например, `+` объединяет строки и списки, а числа складывает.